# File manager (Nautilus) hangs or is ultra slow when listing contents of ssh/sftp server

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, ssh, lubuntu, remote-access

I used to use File --> Connect to server to connect to my remote ssh a lot before 12.04/11.10. But now in a fresh install of 12.04, whenever I try to access the remote files, nautilus either always hangs or is ultra slow (>5 mins) in listing the directory contents. Most of the time I have to force quit or xkill. Mounting using SSHFS works fine. The ssh server is fast and it works fine via putty, mc (using fish) and normal terminal.

I even installed nautilus in Lubuntu 12.04 (virtualbox) and to my surprise, browsing ssh server was fast and smooth. Both versions of nautilus are at 3.4.2 thus I am led to believe the problem might be lying somewhere in Ubuntu 12.04. But I am clueless. All suggestions welcome. I really need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with 12.04 that was not there with 10.04.

when opening any large directory, the Nautilius file manager becomes ultra slow when listing the directory conents. The other installed programs work rapidly as usually.

This problem was not there from the beginning, but appeared after I had installed several programs and filled the harddisk with document files by about 80%.

So there seems to be some weakness in Nautilius that is activated in conjunction with the installation of some other program or just because the amount of files is large.

Jaan

Comment: But Nautilus in Lubuntu 12.04 works fine. This is what puzzles me so I think the problem lies in Ubuntu 12.04 itself.